# Woocommerce - Hide other shipping methods if free shipping is available not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

im trying hide other shipping methods when free delivery is activated but when im adding two different products it shoes all possible shipping methods instead of free delivery only.

When I'm adding a product more than 50euro it's working good but when im adding more than one product it's not working.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'cssigniter_hide_other_methods_when_free_shipping_is_available', 100 );
function cssigniter_hide_other_methods_when_free_shipping_is_available( $rates ) {
    $free = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
```

Comment: The official WooCommerce code still works perfectly in last WooCommerce version, so there is something else that is making trouble, it can be some other custom code, a plugin or your theme.

Comment: any way to find what it breaks my code?

Comment: Sorry, but nobody can guess things by magic...

Comment: indeed. i was asking which is the best way to find the problem. Probably, to deactive all active plugins and check again.

Comment: When is free shipping activated? maybe there is some wrong logic that prevents the free shipping from being activated when you add more than 1 product, or over 50 euro. It depends what rule/requirement you set for free shipping and where/how.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your code is correctly filtering out other shipping methods when free shipping is available, but the issue arises when there are multiple products in the cart.

Check out this alternative:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'cssigniter_hide_other_methods_when_free_shipping_is_available', 100 );
    function cssigniter_hide_other_methods_when_free_shipping_is_available( $rates ) {
        $is_free_shipping_available = false;
        foreach ( $rates as $rate ) {
            if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
                $is_free_shipping_available = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    
        if ( $is_free_shipping_available ) {
            $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
            $free_shipping_threshold = 50; // Adjust this value as needed
    
           if ( $cart_subtotal >= $free_shipping_threshold ) {
                $free = array();
                foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
                    if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
                        $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
            }
        }
    
        return $rates;
    }
```

This code will first check if free shipping is available. If it is, it will then check if the cart subtotal is above the threshold. If both conditions are met, it will keep only the free shipping method; otherwise, it will return all available shipping rates.
Make sure to play around with the $free_shipping_threshold variable according to your own needs.

LMK if this helped.

Comment: It's the same. It isn't working. I'm adding the hook via code snipper and its brings me back all the shipping methods.